# How to you mask a specific column in datagridview?

Tags: vb.net

```
ProductPrice     Stocks     Category
12.0             0          Drinks
50.0             0          Drinks
30.0             0          Drinks
45.0             12         Food
50.0             10         Food
60.0             15         Food
```

this is my datagrid table.
I want to change 0 to n/a.

but the problem is that the Stocks datatype is set to integer in the database.
is there any function to mask a specific column like change 0 to n/a?

I found some "almost" a solution but it changed the whole column to n/a, not the 0's.
also I did tried changing the column value to = n/a but an error always says cannot convert int to string.

can anyone help me?

Comment: Off the top of my head, you would handle the `CellFormatting` event of the grid. You would then filter by column and you can detect specific cell values and specify what should be displayed in the cell for that value. Note that the `Value` of the cell would still be zero but you would specify what to display.

Comment: Actually, I got mixed up there. I was thinking of the `Binding.Format` event. I might still be right but I'm looking into it.

Comment: is this something similar to masking a password column in the datagrid?
because I tried it but it all the columns were affected.

Comment: If what you did affected all columns then you obviously didn't filter by column index first.

Comment: no I mean the Stock column, from top to bottom they were all affected, it should be the 0 should be changed not the whole Stock column.

Comment: Please try to keep up. You said that you tried to mask passwords but what you did affected all columns. If what you did affected all columns then that is because you didn't filter by column before executing the code. If you only want to affect one or more specific columns then you have to write code to check what column the cell raising the event is in first.

Comment: If you actually meant that all rows were affected, rather than all columns, then that's because you didn't filter by value. If you want to format only a specific column and only specific values within that column then you have to check the column and the value and only apply formatting if they are both what you are looking for. That's not programming. That's just logic.

Comment: this is what I did, in Cell.Formatting event
all the Stocks column was affected. also it only takes the "n" not including /a, seems like it accepts only 1 character for masking?

"
        If e.ColumnIndex = 1 AndAlso e.Value IsNot Nothing Then
            e.Value = New String("n/a", e.Value.ToString().Length)
        End If

"

Comment: Why are we only hearing about this now instead of reading it in the question from the outset? You need to provide a FULL and CLEAR explanation of the problem and what you have already tried and what happened when you tried it are part of that. If you've already got 90% of the way there and just made one mistake then there's no point us doing the work to reproduce that 90%. We can just point out where the specific error is and what do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this in an unbound `DataGridView` and it worked as expected:

```vb
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellFormatting(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs) Handles DataGridView1.CellFormatting
    If e.ColumnIndex = 1 Then
        If TypeOf e.Value Is String AndAlso CStr(e.Value) = "0" Then
            e.Value = "N/A"
            e.FormattingApplied = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Note that the fact that that code tests the column index first and only proceeds if the cell being formatted is in the specific column of interest. If you don't do that then of course cells in every column will be affected. You need to filter for the index of the column you want. If `Stocks` is the second column then the index would be 1, just as in my example. If it's not, you need to change it.

This code looks for a `String` value because everything entered into an unbound grid will be a `String`. If you have bound your grid to a data source that actually contains numbers then you should look for the appropriate numeric type. Given the scenario, that would presumably be `Integer`, so you would want something like this:

```vb
If TypeOf e.Value Is Integer AndAlso CInt(e.Value) = 0 Then
```

Comment: I'm sorry for not explaining it correctly or clearly to you, but you actually solved this. Thank you very much!

Comment: @limelatte, all's well that ends well, but you know for next time.